# Подключение System.Data.SQLite в JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, sqlite, jetbrains, rider

При выполнении этого кода [image: код]

возникает следующая ошибка[image: ошибка]

гугл и стаковер мне уже не помогли(
На windows в vs2017 всё работает исправно, перенес программу на компьютер под управлением Ubuntu Mate 16.04 и запускал в последней версии JetBrains Rider.

установленные библиотеки :[image: библиотеки]

конфигурация проекта :
[image: конф]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установленная версия .NET в системе - 2.0.0
Mono - 5.4.1.6
Файл SQLite.Interop.dll находится и около .exe файла и автоматически сгенерированных папках.

Comment: Для работы в Linux надо использовать `Entity Framework Core`, а не как вы стали использовать старую версию `Entity Framework 6`, которая работает только в винде.

Comment: @Bulson с ef core, получается, нельзя использовать System.data.SQLite? не хотелось бы переходить, тк проект уже написан с использованием этого пакета

Comment: А вам шашечки или ехать? Или тогда эксплуатируйте проект в винде.